# How do I ignore local git changes but still ensure I get upstream changes?

Tags: git, github

I have a config file that is checked in and is updated sometimes, but not frequently. I need to make a change in it so that it works for my specific local developer environment, but I don't want to just ignore the file because when someone changes it upstream, I want to make sure I pull any new changes.

What I want is to have my local changes ignored, and if the pull conflicts with my local, for git to just let me know. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

What I do is check in an exemplar file and ignore the actual file.  For example, if you need `setup.json` in your directory, that's edited for your own directory structure and preferences and whatnot, I'd check in a prototype called `setup.json.EXEMPLAR` that has placeholders and instructions of what needs to be set locally.

Comment: This is the right answer and it also mirrors [the answer in the Git FAQ}(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfilehttps://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile).